# Type error: JSX element type '{} | null | undefined' is not a constructor function for JSX elements

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-apollo

I have a React component called `HandleQuery` that handles the results of an Apollo GraphQL query:

```
import React, { ReactNode } from 'react';

import { CenteredMessage } from './centered-message';

export interface HandleQueryProps {
    loading: boolean,
    error?: Error,
    children: ReactNode
}

export const HandleQuery = ({ loading, error, children }: HandleQueryProps) => {
    if (loading) {
        return <CenteredMessage>Loading...</CenteredMessage>;
    }

    if (error) {
        return <CenteredMessage>{error.message}</CenteredMessage>;
    }

    return children;
};
```

When this component is used in another component it does not compile:

```
import React from 'react';

import { useQuery } from 'react-apollo-hooks';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { HandleQuery } from '..';
import { MutationType } from '../../graphql-types';
import { AuthorsPanel } from './authors-panel';
import { GET_AUTHORS } from './authors-queries';
import { AuthorMutated } from './__generated__/AuthorMutated';

export class AuthorsContainer extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_AUTHORS);
        return (
            <!-- THIS LINE PRODUCES A COMPILER ERROR -->
            <HandleQuery loading={loading} error={error}>
                <AuthorsPanel data={data} />
            </HandleQuery>
        );
    }
}
```

The use of `HandleQuery` above produces the following error:

> Type error: JSX element type '{} | null | undefined' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.
>     Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Element | null'.  TS2605

What does this mean and how can I get rid of it?

**Update**

Converting AuthorsContainer to a function component does not eliminate the error:

```
export const AuthorsContainer = () => {
    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_AUTHORS);
    return (
        <HandleQuery loading={loading} error={error}>
            <AuthorsPanel data={data} />
        </HandleQuery>
    );
};
```

**Update 2**
Implemented suggestion from @FredyC:

```
import React from 'react';

import { CenteredMessage } from './centered-message';

export interface HandleQueryProps {
    loading: boolean;
    error?: Error;
}

export const HandleQuery: React.FC<HandleQueryProps> = ({
    loading,
    error,
    children
}) => {
    if (loading) {
        return <CenteredMessage>Loading...</CenteredMessage>;
    }

    if (error) {
        return <CenteredMessage>{error.message}</CenteredMessage>;
    }

    return children;
};
```

Now the error on the container component has gone away, but a new compiler error has popped up on the `HandleQuery` component:

```
Type error: Type '({ loading, error, children }: PropsWithChildren<HandleQueryProps>) => {} | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<HandleQueryProps>'.
  Type '{} | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null'.
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null'.  TS2322
```

Comment: Start `console.log()`ing everything. Find out what is null. From what it seems like `HandleQuery` is undefined. Perhaps you meant `import { HandleQuery } from '../'`?

Comment: @FrankerZ - This is a *compile-time* error (TSnnnn is a TypeScript compiler error code), not a runtime error. (The OP also conveniently said "this line produces a compiler error" although in his case, he used all caps.)

Comment: Can hooks be used in classes? I thought they were functional component only?

Comment: HandleQuery is imported correctly. It is defined in ../index.tsx

Comment: Just read the Hooks FAQ. It says "You can’t use Hooks inside of a class component". Let me try to convert that to a function component.

Comment: Converting AuthorsContainer to a function component does not eliminate the error. See my update.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There is a long term issue regarding ReactNode. I don't understand specifics, but it's something hard-wired in TypeScript itself and is being worked on.

Either way, a solution should be easy. Don't use ReactNode with functional components :) The `children` prop is implicitly included in React.FC type.

The same problem goes with returning children. It can be either overcome by wrapping into `<React.Fragment>` or `<div>` if you prefer, but since it's just a type error, you can convince TypeScript that you know what you are doing :)

```
import React, { ReactNode } from 'react';

import { CenteredMessage } from './centered-message';

export interface HandleQueryProps {
    loading: boolean,
    error?: Error,
}

export const HandleQuery: React.FC<HandleQueryProps> = ({ loading, error, children }) => {
    if (loading) {
        return <CenteredMessage>Loading...</CenteredMessage>;
    }

    if (error) {
        return <CenteredMessage>{error.message}</CenteredMessage>;
    }

    return children as ReactElement<any>;
};
```

Comment: Hi Fredy, now the error on the container component has gone away, but a new compiler error has popped up on the HandleQuery component. Please see my update 2.

Comment: I think it would be best if you create codesandbox.io to demonstrate the issue. It's hard to guess what's wrong without seeing a whole picture. No need to set up Apollo there, of course, you can simulate that.

Comment: Was difficult to demo using codesandbox.io because it uses a different version of TypeScript. Here's a very simple repo that shows the issue: https://github.com/nareshbhatia/simple-react

Comment: Ah right, fixed the answer. Focus on the last code line and 3rd paragraph for explanation.

Comment: Wow, I would have never thought about that! Thanks, so much.

Comment: I had the same issue and changed my objects to use the last syntax you posted. It worked fine for almost everything, except a component with type parameters. Any way to use FunctionalComponent there?

Comment: Generics are for its own question, but check this ... https://spectrum.chat/react/general/typescript-generic-functional-components~9951d01e-a94e-435c-97f9-099208a00436

Comment: This is still a problem, so I don't think we can any longer say it's being worked on.

Answer (score 3):

At this case, it can be more easy simply define `children` of type `ReactElement` if I am not obviating something.

```
export interface HandleQueryProps {
    loading: boolean,
    error?: ApolloError,
    children: ReactElement
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Switching `ReactNode` to `JSX.Element` resolves the type issue.

According to [the related github issue on React](https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react/issues/129#issuecomment-508412266), using `JSX.Element` instead of `ReactNode` is suggested for functional components.

You can check the details of `JSX.Element` vs `ReactNode` in [typescript-cheatsheets/react page](https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react/blob/cc2ec67e0b36b7e838df8f2a54b4cd84df6c78cd/README.md#useful-react-prop-type-examples).

Answer (score 0):

my solution for this case, it works with [Typescript Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html)

QueryWrapper.ts

```
import { QueryResult } from "@apollo/client/react/types/types";

interface Props<TData, TVariables> {
  query: QueryResult<TData, TVariables>;
  children: (data: TData) => any;
}

export function QueryWrapper<TData, TVariables>({ query, children }: Props<TData, TVariables>) {
  if (query.loading) {
    return "loading...";
  }

  if (query.error) {
    return query.error.message;
  }

  if (!query.data) {
    return "Data is empty"
  }

  return children(query.data as TData);
}
```

usage:

```
const recipeQuery = useQuery<{ recipes: Recipe[] }>(GET_RECIPES);

<QueryWrapper query={recipeQuery}>
    {({recipes}) => (
       JSON.stringify(recipes)
    )}
</QueryWrapper>
```

Answer (score -5):

for me this command solved the problem:

`rm -rf node_modules && rm yarn.lock && yarn`